# Boot VM from USB on Windows host without admin rights

Tags: windows, usb, virtualbox, administrator, qemu

I have a Linux installed on a USB flash drive, and I'd like, when I only have access to a Windows machine with no access to boot order and no admin rights, to be able to boot from my USB drive with a Virtual Machine.

I tried to create a "raw vmdk" file using the following VirtualBox command:

```
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename usb.vmdk -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive1
```

But sadly, it seems that I need to have admin rights to not only create, but also use that file.

I also tried directly with QEMU and the following command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64.exe -smp 2 -m 8G -usb -drive file=\\.\PhysicalDrive1,if=none,id=usbdrive1 -device usb-storage,drive=usbdrive1
```

It has the same problem (even using `-hda` and/or `-snapshot`).

So are there any way to boot a Virtual Machine from a USB flash drive on a Windows host without admin rights?
Or is it impossible, and if so, why?

P.S.: I know that, without admin rights, it'll be nearly impossible to not have a very slow VM, but it would be better than nothing

Comment: USB passthrough maybe? Not sure if that requires admin right or supports booting

Comment: @TomYan any idea how to do this on Windows ? I'm trying on my own but the BIOS can't find anything to boot from for now...

Comment: @TomYan ah, I finally found the bus and addr thanks to qemu monitor, but I have the following error: "failed to open host usb device"... and strangely, I have no error when I try to add a device with wrong bus and addr

Comment: Oh I meant with VirtualBox (and its official extension pack). Never really used qemu on Windows.